# Defining a "See, for Example, Someplace Else in the Index" Command

Tags: macros, indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, idxlayout

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\newcommand{\forexample}[2]{\emph{ See, for example,} #1} 

\begin{document}
\large
Some words. \newpage
Some words.\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}! 01  A regular entry@A regular entry}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}! 02 A different entry@A different entry\forexample{\textbf{SOMEPLACE ELSE}}}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the Index:

[image]

As you can see, the output is producing a page number (minus the comma) for this "see someplace else" entry.

QUESTION: Might someone point out to me what I am doing wrong? I don't want the page number from which the *see, for example* command originates to appear.

Thank you.

Comment: isn't this the standard functionality of `|see{something else}` apart from minor wording changes?

Comment: @David Carlisle Without getting into details, what you suggest is not appropriate for what I would be using it for. Aside from that, do you have an idea what may be causing the unwanted page number in the MWE? Many thanks.

Comment: probably then you should clarify the question as it seems you want exactly what `|see` does except the trivial change of making it say see for example rather than just see, so I can't guess an answer.

Comment: you are writing out `\forexample{\textbf{SOMEPLACE ELSE}}, 2` so `#2` is the comma, and you print 2.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thanks. I'll try to figure out what you're saying. Unfortunately, I see only `\forexample{\textbf{SOMEPLACE ELSE}}` with no comma followed by a 2. Perhaps it'll hit me.

Comment: look in the `.ind` file with the latex you have generated, it has `\subitem A different entry\forexample{\textbf{SOMEPLACE ELSE}}, 2` so you discard the comma and print the 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the "see"-feature within an index-entry, then you don't type `\see` but you type `|see`.

Analogously don't type

```
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}! 02 A different entry@A different
entry\forexample{\textbf{SOMEPLACE ELSE}}}
```

but type

```
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}! 02 A different entry@A different
entry|forexample{\textbf{SOMEPLACE ELSE}}}
```

, i.e, `|forexample` instead of `\forexample`.

When in your code in the index-entry I change `\forexample` to `|forexample`,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\newcommand{\forexample}[2]{\emph{ See, for example,} #1} 

\begin{document}
\large
Some words. \newpage
Some words.\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}! 01  A regular entry@A regular entry}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}! 02 A different entry@A different entry|forexample{\textbf{SOMEPLACE ELSE}}}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

, then I get this result:

[image]

When looking at this result, I get the impression that your code for the macro `\forexample`

1. contains a spurious space in the argument of `\emph`
2. should use the word "see", not "See".

I., e., instead of

`\newcommand{\forexample}[2]{\emph{ See, for example,} #1}`

it should be

`\newcommand{\forexample}[2]{\emph{see, for example,} #1}`.

With these modifications,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\newcommand{\forexample}[2]{\emph{see, for example,} #1} 

\begin{document}
\large
Some words. \newpage
Some words.\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}! 01  A regular entry@A regular entry}
\index{HEADING@\textbf{HEADING}! 02 A different entry@A different entry|forexample{\textbf{SOMEPLACE ELSE}}}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

, you get:

[image]

Comment: Danke schön, for another very helpful answer.